# Need help Reading and displaying pdf in browser window using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
functiononClickFunction(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "http:URLToGetFile", true); 
        request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        request.onload = function (e) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var arraybuffer=this.response;
                console.log(this.response);
                var pdffile = new Blob([arraybuffer],{type: "application/pdf"});
                var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdffile);
                window.open(fileURL);
            };
        };
        request.send();
    }
```

I am trying to display a pdf in new window on click of a button, but it is showing error "Failed to load PDF document". Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe I'm being too native but couldn't you just call window.open with the actual (http[s]) URL of the PDF file?

Comment: @glutengo : May be he is not having any URL and generating bytes to display pdf

Comment: @user2486 But he is doing an AJAX request to a http URL (which would replace "http:URLToGetFile", right?) and then creates an ObjectURL of the result which is passed to window.open - I don't get what's the benefit of the AJAX request

Comment: you need to request ajax to get byte code, dynamically generated